# Read a definite number of lines in a text file, using java

Tags: java, file, line, readfile, datainputstream

I have a text file with data. The file has information from all months. Imagine that the information for January occupy 50 lines. Than February starts and it occupies 40 more lines. Than I have March and so on... Is it possible to read only part of the file? Can I say "read from line X to line Y"? or is there a better way to accomplish this? I only want to print the data correspondent to one month not the all file. Here is my code

```
public static void readFile()
{
  try
  {
     DataInputStream inputStream = 
     new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("SpreadsheetDatabase2013.txt"));

   while(inputStream.available() != 0)
   {
     System.out.println("AVAILABLE: " + inputStream.available());
     System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
     System.out.println(inputStream.readInt());
     for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
     {
       System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
       System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
       System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
       System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
       System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
       System.out.println(inputStream.readDouble());
       System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
       System.out.println(inputStream.readBoolean());
       System.out.println();
     }
   }// end while
   inputStream.close();
 }// end try
 catch (Exception e)
 {
   System.out.println("An error has occurred.");
 }//end catch
}//end method
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: is there a way to tell where the data changes? (e.g. from jan to feb) Can you give some sample data?

Comment: It depends on the layout. For example how can we recognize where one month starts?

Comment: I am not sure. If I could use a search method to find when a month start and when it ends I guess...

Comment: You can't "seek" to a line in a file with variable-length lines -- you must read from the start and count lines.  If the file is reused frequently, however, you can construct a side table of the seek offsets to the lines of possible interest.

Comment: if the month (or some other unique factor) is present, you could store the initial month and check each successive piece of data against it, then break the loop if they ever don't match

Comment: I see... Let's say that I want to show only March. I would create a search method that would give me the line number, or bytes where March is and where it ends. Could I use that in any way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: @Daniel the problem with that is that I think that there is no particular relationship between the String "March" and the rest of the information below. The only think telling that the data belongs to March is that it is between "March" and "April"

Comment: so the data is stored like 

`March`
`data...`
`April`

with the actual string displaying the month on its own line?

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this would be to read the entire contents of the text file and store it in a ArrayList and read only the lines for the requested month.

**Example:**

Use this function to read the all the lines from the file.

```
/**
 * Read from a file specified by the filePath.
 * 
 * @param filePath
 *            The path of the file.
 * @return List of lines in the file.
 * @throws IOException
 */

public static ArrayList<String> readFromFile(String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (file.exists()) {
        BufferedReader brin;
        brin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line = brin.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if (!line.equals(""))
                temp.add(line);
            line = brin.readLine();
        }
        brin.close();
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Then read only the ones you need from ArrayList ***temp***.

**Example:**

if you want to read February month's data assuming its 50 lines of data and starts from 40th line.

```
for(int i=40;i<90;i++)
{
    System.out.println(temp.get(i));
}
```

***Note: This is only just one way of doing this. I am not certain if there is any other way!***

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java 7, you can use [Files.readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29), e.g.

```
Path path = // Path to "SpreadsheetDatabase2013.txt"
Charset charset = // "UTF-8" or whatever charset is used
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
List<String> relevantLines = allLines.subList(x, y);
```

Where `x` (inclusive) and `y` (exclusive) indicates the line numbers that are of interest, see  [List.subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29).

One benefit of this solution, as stated in the JavaDoc of `readAllLines()`:

> This method ensures that the file is closed when all bytes have been read or an I/O error, or other runtime exception, is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you said your data was organized, I would suggest doing something like this

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
int read = 0;
File file = new File(filePath);
if (file.exists()) {
    BufferedReader brin;
    brin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String line = brin.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        if (!line.equals("")){
            if(line.equals("March"))
                read = 1;
            else if(line.equals("April"))
                break;
            else if(read == 1)
                temp.add(line);
        }
        line = brin.readLine();
    }
    brin.close();
```

Just tried it myself, that'll take in all the data between March and April. You can adjust them as necessary or make them variables. Thanks to ngoa for the foundation code. Credit where credit is due

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html).

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filename);`

Use `scanner.nextLine()` to get each of the lines of the file. If you only want from line x to line y you can use a for loop to scan each of the lines that you don't need before going through the scanner for the lines you do need. Be careful not to hit an exception without throwing it though.

Or you can go through the scanner and for each line, add the String contents of the line to an ArrayList. Good luck.